# Multiple header files to one source file?

Tags: c, header-files

I have a source file called source.c and a public header file called source.h. The source.c contain  s

```
#include "source.h"
```

I do not want all the functions in source.c to be public, therefore I want another header file called priv_source.h that refers to some private functions in source.c.

Do the compiler understand that priv_source.h also is a header file to source.c or do I have to make another c-file called priv_source.c?

Comment: Why you `include` `source.c` into `source.h`?

Comment: That was wrong, It should be the other way as I edited now...

Comment: Conventionally, the file `source.h` does not contain declarations for every function defined in `source.c`, just those functions intended to be shared with other source files (translation units). For any function in `source.c` that you do not wish to export from `source.c`, do not declare it in `source.h`. If a function needs a declaration (because it is used before it is defined), then simply declare it at an appropriate place in `source.c`. Additionally, functions intended to be private to `source.c` would usually be declared with `static`.

Answer (score 8):

> Do the compiler understand that `priv_source.h` also is a header file to `source.c` or do I have to make another c-file called `priv_source.c`?

C compiler does not make any such connection: all files, headers and sources, are unrelated to the compiler. All it knows is the name(s) of the translation units that it needs to process (i.e. the names of your .c files) and the names of headers that these translation units include.

It is common to split declarations in two parts - the public and the private ones. In such cases, however, the private header would include the public one, like this:

source.h

```
// Public declarations go here
void public_function1(int, int);
void public_function2(int, double, int);
```

priv_source.h

```
#include "source.h"
void private_function1(float);
void private_function2(char*);
```

source.c

```
#include "priv_source.h"
```

Comment: It should be the other way, the source.c contains #include "source.h", sorry

Comment: @theva OK, I removed the first part of the answer, and expanded the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points in your question:

1. Function declarations are put into header files so that they can be
   included into multiple source files, without explicit need to
   declare in each and every source file. So, only put those declaration in header file which you *WANT* to be available to other files as well.
2. If some function need to be restricted to a particular file, make
   that function definition as `static`. Once you define a function as
   `static`, it will not be visible from outside for linking. The scope
   of that function will be limited to the same compilation unit,
   usually that file only.

Answer (score 0):

In c by default all function are public means a function declare inside any header can be used by other method if that function simply include the header. Now if you explicitly declare a function like static return_type name(some arguments may or may not) then this can't be access out side of that file. Now there is no such privilege to hide any function like java, c++ and c# etc. May be this can be I am not sure can be achieve by using #if #elseif and #endif statement. You have to write logic if you that function present in your code then put in #if. Because in #if statement if condition is not satisfy then after preprocessor stage that part will vanish from our code similar to comments in our code. See I am not sure but may be.
Thanks 
asif aftab